# Command to find out the version number of a .pkg file

Tags: macos, command-line, install, pkg

Does anyone know how to retrieve the version number of a .pkg file which isn't installed yet?

I'd like to use something like **pkgutil --pkg-info**, but that only works for installed packages.

I've also tried **installer -pkginfo -verbose**, but that doesn't show the version number.

Is there a built-in command to do this, or alternatively, could someone suggest a one-liner please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best I could come up with was this:

```
pkgutil --expand package.pkg /tmp/pkg; cat /tmp/pkg/PackageInfo | grep ./Applications | grep -m 1 .app\" | awk '{ print $3, $2 }'; rm -rf /tmp/pkg
```

Not the most elegant solution, so I'm still searching for a way to do this without having to extract the .pkg first.

Comment: Have you found any better solution yet ?? I do not see any effect to changing package version number when building the pkg file. The final package always seem to replace the existing files anyway, isnt it ?

Answer (score 3):

Variation of @d3Xt3r answer:

```bsh
tar xOvf PackageName.pkg output.pkg/PackageInfo 2>/dev/null | grep '<pkg-info' \
    | sed "s#.* version=\"\([0-9\.]*\)\".*#\1#"
```

Advantage is that this is only pipe processing.

Note my package had different structure, there is an extra directory `output.pkg` which contains file `PackageInfo`

Answer (score 0):

for a package structured as below,

```
PackageName.pkg
└── Package.pkg
    └── PackageInfo
```

*adapted from [@Marek R](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/152097/marek-r)*

the command to extract version information inline is:

```
tar xOvf "PackageName.pkg" "Package.pkg/PackageInfo" 2>/dev/null | fgrep "<pkg-info" | grep -Po '(?<!-)version="[^"]+"'
```